# Cosmos db high RUs for writes

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

In cosmos Db hope are RUs increased for writes? To my understanding, the replicas are only for reads but only one node is used for writes. What is the model for writes distribution in cosmos db when the load is high?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question fully. Are you asking if your write cost goes up with each additional region? If so, then yes, as documented, you have RU cost for every region you write to. Maybe your question is about something else? Please edit for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Cosmos DB, data is stored by it's partition key. In high write volume scenarios a key to success is ensuring your partition key has high enough cardinality to give you enough throughput to meet your performance needs for a given amount of RU/s.

Beyond scalability in a single geographic region though, using multi-master is what provides geographic scale for writes or lower latency.